# App Startup Page exception

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

For my WP8 app i need a startup page to be shown before the actual home screen, in order to take user preferences that affect the behaviour of the app.

For this I'm currently using this code sample in the `OnLaunched` method of `App.xaml.cpp`

```
Windows::Storage::ApplicationDataContainer^ localSettings = ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings;
// in case there's no "firstStartup" key, create it
if (localSettings->Values->HasKey("firstStartup") == false)
    localSettings->Values->Insert("firstStartup", dynamic_cast<PropertyValue^>(PropertyValue::CreateBoolean(true)));

// on (first) app startup, show startup dialog
bool firstStartup = safe_cast<bool>(localSettings->Values->Lookup("firstStartup"));
if (firstStartup)
    rootFrame->Navigate(StartupPage::typeid);
else
    rootFrame->Navigate(HomePage::typeid);
```

If I deploy the app for the first time the page shows up accordingly, but in the debug window of VS2013 the following text is shown:

> First-chance exception at 0x7784210B (KERNELBASE.DLL) in gymlog.exe: 0x000006BA: The RPC server is unavailable.
>
> First-chance exception at 0x7784210B (KERNELBASE.DLL) in gymlog.exe: 0x0000000E: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

This only shows up on the first launch, after that the message is gone! Is this something I should be concerned about?